# Why is the standard error of interaction different?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, interaction, standard-error

I would like to know and understand why an interaction in a linear model yields different standard errors than simple effects.

Here is an example in R with $n=25$, no correlation between simple effects, and all $\beta = 0$. I recorded standard errors of regression coefficients in a model with an interaction term (`SD`), another model with three simple effects (no interaction; `SD2`) and the covariance  matrix `COV` and the inverted covariance matrix (`ICOV`, plus some higher order moments.

```
n <- 25
nreps <- 10000
COV <- ICOV <- matrix(0, nrow = nreps, ncol = 15)
colnames(COV) <- colnames(ICOV) <- c("X_X","X_W","X_XW","X_X2","X_W2","W_W",
                                     "W_XW","W_X2","W_W2","XW_XW","XW_X2",
                                     "XW_W2","X2_X2","X2_W2","W2_W2")
SD <- SD2 <-  matrix(0, nrow = nreps, ncol = 3)

for(i in 1:nreps){
  # Generate data
  D <- as.data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n, mu = rep(0,3), Sigma = diag(3)))
  D[,4] <- D[,2] * D[,3]
  colnames(D) <- c("Y","X","W","XW")
  z <- scale(rlnorm(n))
  
  # Record the lower diagonal elements of the covariance matrix
  COV[i,] <- cov(cbind(D[,-1], X2 = D[,2]^2, W2 = D[,3]^2))[lower.tri(diag(5), diag = TRUE)]
  
  # Record the lower diagonal elements of the inverted covariance matrix
  ICOV[i,] <- solve(cov(cbind(D[,-1], X2 = D[,2]^2, W2 = D[,3]^2)))[lower.tri(diag(5), diag = TRUE)]
  
  # Record the standard errors of the interaction model
  SD[i,] <- summary(lm(Y ~ X * W, data = D))$coefficient[2:4,"Std. Error"]
  
  # Record the standard errors of only simple effects model
  SD2[i,] <- summary(lm(Y ~ X + W + z, data = D))$coefficient[2:4,"Std. Error"]
}

> round(colMeans(SD), 4)
[1] 0.2279 0.2267 0.2552
> round(colMeans(SD2), 4)
[1] 0.2181 0.2172 0.2112
> round(colMeans(COV), 4)
    X_X     X_W    X_XW    X_X2    X_W2     W_W    W_XW    W_X2    W_W2   XW_XW   XW_X2   XW_W2   X2_X2 
 0.9990  0.0017 -0.0045 -0.0026  0.0016  1.0084  0.0006 -0.0023 -0.0004  1.0015 -0.0058  0.0032  1.9948 
  X2_W2   W2_W2 
-0.0064  2.0315 
> round(colMeans(ICOV), 4)
    X_X     X_W    X_XW    X_X2    X_W2     W_W    W_XW    W_X2    W_W2   XW_XW   XW_X2   XW_W2   X2_X2 
 1.7785 -0.0018  0.0171  0.0118 -0.0006  1.7603 -0.0038  0.0067  0.0099  2.4783  0.0108 -0.0064  1.2861 
  X2_W2   W2_W2 
 0.0509  1.2736
```

Here, it shows that the standard error of the interaction terms is $.2552$ whereas we should expect it to be $\approx .21$. Any ideas why? And if yes, any ideas how to compute the difference beforehand?

Comment: `XW` is correlated with `X` and with `W`. Multicollinearity inflates standard errors and the VIF of `XW` will be higher than the VIFs of `X` and `W`.

Comment: @Roland, not sure is multicollinearity is important here as we can uncorrelate `X, W, XW` see https://rdcu.be/dozuc . The expected correlation is also very close to 0.